# Icon in my Menu shows up way too big. How can I have it fit in the little square?

Tags: c#, wpf, menu

[image]

```
<MenuItem Header="Language" Background="#2E404B">
    MenuItem.Icon>
        <Image Source="MenuImages/speechbubble.png" Stretch="Fill" />
    </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

How can I make it so the bubble fits nicely into the square box? Or even better, is there a way for my text to be a bit lower to hit the middle of the image. I wouldn't mind having a big image if I can move the text a bit lower.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set the size on your image:

```
<Image Source="MenuImages/speechbubble.png" Stretch="Fill" Height="16" Width="16" />
```

WPF seems to pay attention to the DPI settings in images and scales them accordingly. If you omit the height and width on an image then it can be a little unpredictable.

You can, of course, set those properties at the top level. Perhaps in the Menu's resources:

```
<Menu>
    <Menu.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="16" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="16" />
        </Style>
    </Menu.Resources>
</Menu>
```